# Prove that class of models isomorphic to some infinite model $M$ is not countably axiomatizable

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In a related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897269/axiomatizability-of-finite-isomorphic-classes) the author posted similar problem for finite models, and stated that in case of an infinite model the class of models isomorphic to the given one is not with FO-axiomatizable, which can be proved with Löwenheim-Skolem theorem.

Unfortunately I can't see how one can relate the isomorphy of the models to the theorem. Maybe someone could give a hint on this? Thank you.

Comment: Is the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem the one that says, if $M$ is an infinite model, then $M$ has an elementary extension $N$ whose cardinality is greater than the cardinality of $M$? So $N$ satisfies all of the first-order sentences which hold in $M$? But $N$ and $M$ are not isomorphic because their cardinalities are different? What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks, I guess this argument does it. I didn't make it to relate cardinality to the isomorphy, I guess.